# hadoop fs operations file not found

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I installed and configured hadoop recently on my ubuntu 12.04 operated machine. The installation was successful and I am able to start all services successfully.
I am facing problem with hadoop fs . I think I have set it up correctly since hadoop fs is not giving any error like command not found. I am facing error while doing any operation with hadoop fs like ls, put, copyFromLocal.

Every operation ends up in showing `No such file or directory` error though being provided with valid path. 
Please help me solve this.

Output by hdfs

```
recmach@chetan-HP-ENVY-15-Notebook-PC:~/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.1/sbin$ hadoop fs -ls /home/recmach
ls: `/home/recmach': No such file or directory
```

Output by ls for same directory

```
recmach@chetan-HP-ENVY-15-Notebook-PC:~/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.1/sbin$ ls -l /home/recmach
total 52
drwxr-xr-x 2 recmach hadoop 4096 Oct 21 13:57 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 2 recmach hadoop 4096 Oct 21 13:57 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 2 recmach hadoop 4096 Oct 21 15:27 Downloads
-rw-r--r-- 1 recmach hadoop 8445 Oct 21 11:56 examples.desktop
drwxrwxr-x 3 recmach hadoop 4096 Oct 21 13:10 hadoop
drwxr-xr-x 2 recmach hadoop 4096 Oct 21 13:57 Music
drwxr-xr-x 2 recmach hadoop 4096 Oct 21 13:57 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x 3 recmach hadoop 4096 Oct 21 15:58 Public
drwxr-xr-x 2 recmach hadoop 4096 Oct 21 13:57 Templates
drwxr-xr-x 4 recmach hadoop 4096 Oct 21 14:50 tmp
drwxr-xr-x 2 recmach hadoop 4096 Oct 21 13:57 Videos
```

Comment: what paths have you tried to do ls, put, etc. on? What is the output of `hadoop fs -ls /`  ?

Comment: Output is nothing. Not working for any absolute path like /home or /home/<my-user>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when we execute **`hadoop fs -ls .`**, **`Hadoop`**, by default, looks for **`/user/<current login user>`**

Since you are facing error **`No such file or directory`**, it seems that **`/user/<current login user>`** doesn't exist in **`hdfs`**.

To fix this issue, execute following command

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/<current login user>
```

where "current login user" is linux username.

> recmach@chetan-HP-ENVY-15-Notebook-PC:~/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.1/sbin$ hadoop fs -ls /home/recmach
>   ls: `/home/recmach': No such file or directory

/home/recmarch doesn't exist on HDFS and hence error. Try following command

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /home/recmarch
```

Comment: But it also giving NoFileFoundError for /home or any other absolute path

Comment: which command is throwing NoFileFoundError? check if path exists or not.

Comment: path exists . Files are listed by ls -l too. I cannot even use -put for the same reason because it does not identify any absolute path

Comment: post exact command you are trying to execute. Did you run hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/<current login user>

Comment: put command should look like hadoop fs -put localfile /user/hadoop/hadoopfile

Answer (score 1):

No output for `hadoop fs -ls /` shows that your hdfs is empty.
The reason you are getting FileNotFound is because you are trying absolute path from your local filesystem.

Try creating a drirectory iun HDFS and list directory.

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /abcd
hadoop fs -ls /
```

You should get an output like

> drwxr-xr-x   - user supergroup          0 2015-10-21 17:33 /abcd

You should understand that HDFS is different from your local file system.

Now you want to copy a file from your local file system to HDFS, for this use `haddop fs -put <file on local filesystem> <destination path on HDFS>`.

```
date > current_time.txt #creates a new file
hadoop fs -put current_time.txt /abcd/
hadoop fs -ls /abcd
```

Should give you the output like

> -rw-r--r--   3 user supergroup         26 2015-10-21 17:35 /abcd/current_time.txt

Comment: Please elaborate so how else to provide absolute path for hdfs. I am beginner

Comment: working but how would I then specify path fo put some file from local filesystem to hdfs